# How to remove specific elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I remove some specific elements from a numpy array? Say I have

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

I then want to remove `3,4,7` from `a`. All I know is the index of the values (`index=[2,3,6]`).

Answer (score 449, accepted):

Use [`numpy.delete()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), which returns a *new* array with sub-arrays along an axis deleted.

```
numpy.delete(a, index)
```

For your specific question:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
index = [2, 3, 6]

new_a = np.delete(a, index)

print(new_a)
# Output: [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Note that `numpy.delete()` returns a new array since [array scalars](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html) are immutable, similar to strings in Python, so each time a change is made to it, a new object is created. I.e., to quote the `delete()` [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

> "A *copy* of arr with the elements specified by obj removed. *Note that
> delete does not occur in-place*..."

If the code I post has output, it is the result of running the code.

Answer (score 119):

Use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b = np.array([3,4,7])
>>> c = np.setdiff1d(a,b)
>>> c
array([1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Good to know. I was thinking that np.delete would be slower but alas, timeit for 1000 integers says delete is x2 faster.

Comment: It is important to note that this is a set difference, so if there are duplicate elements in the array, they will be removed as well. Consider the case where 
```a = np.array([-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,99])``` and ```b=np.array([-1,99])``` then 
```c= np.setdiff1d(a,b) => array( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ] )```

Answer (score 55):

A Numpy array is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), meaning you technically cannot delete an item from it. However, you can construct a *new* array without the values you don't want, like this:

```
b = np.delete(a, [2,3,6])
```

Comment: technically, numpy arrays ARE mutable. For example, this: `a[0]=1` modifies `a` in place. But they can not be resized.

Comment: The definition says its immutable, but if by assigning new value it let you modify, then hows it immutable?

Comment: The element of an array is mutable then?

Answer (score 51):

To delete by value :

```
modified_array = np.delete(original_array, np.where(original_array == value_to_delete))
```

Comment: From numpy 1.19 one can just do:
`np.delete(original_array, original_array==value)`
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Answer (score 12):

Using `np.delete` is the fastest way to do it, if we know the indices of the elements that we want to remove. However, for completeness, let me add another way of "removing" array elements using a boolean mask created with the help of `np.isin`. This method allows us to remove the elements by specifying them directly or by their indices:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

**Remove by indices**:

```
indices_to_remove = [2, 3, 6]
a = a[~np.isin(np.arange(a.size), indices_to_remove)]
```

**Remove by elements** (don't forget to recreate the original `a` since it was rewritten in the previous line):

```
elements_to_remove = a[indices_to_remove]  # [3, 4, 7]
a = a[~np.isin(a, elements_to_remove)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Not being a numpy person, I took a shot with:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> index=[2,3,6]
>>> a = np.array(list(itertools.compress(a, [i not in index for i in range(len(a))])))
>>> a
array([1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

According to my tests, this outperforms `numpy.delete()`. I don't know why that would be the case, maybe due to the small size of the initial array?

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np" -s "import itertools" -s "a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])" -s "index=[2,3,6]" "a = np.array(list(itertools.compress(a, [i not in index for i in range(len(a))])))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.9 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np" -s "a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])" -s "index=[2,3,6]" "np.delete(a, index)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 usec per loop
```

That's a pretty significant difference (in the opposite direction to what I was expecting), anyone have any idea why this would be the case?

Even more weirdly, passing `numpy.delete()` a list performs worse than looping through the list and giving it single indices.

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np" -s "a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])" -s "index=[2,3,6]" "for i in index:" "    np.delete(a, i)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.8 usec per loop
```

Edit: It does appear to be to do with the size of the array. With large arrays, `numpy.delete()` is significantly faster.

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np" -s "import itertools" -s "a = np.array(list(range(10000)))" -s "index=[i for i in range(10000) if i % 2 == 0]" "a = np.array(list(itertools.compress(a, [i not in index for i in range(len(a))])))"
10 loops, best of 3: 200 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np" -s "a = np.array(list(range(10000)))" -s "index=[i for i in range(10000) if i % 2 == 0]" "np.delete(a, index)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 msec per loop
```

Obviously, this is all pretty irrelevant, as you should always go for clarity and avoid reinventing the wheel, but I found it a little interesting, so I thought I'd leave it here.

Comment: Be careful with what you actually compare! You have `a = delte_stuff(a)` in your first iteration, which makes `a` smaller with every iteration. When you use the inbuild function, you don't store the value back to a, which keeps a in the original size! Besides that, you can speed up your function drastically, when you create a set ouf of `index` and check against that, whether or not to delete an item. Fixing both things, I get for 10k items:
6.22 msec per loop with your function, 4.48 msec for `numpy.delete`, which is roughly what you would expect.

Comment: Two more hints: Instead of `np.array(list(range(x)))` use `np.arange(x)`, and for creating the index, you can use `np.s_[::2]`.

Answer (score 6):

In case you don't have the indices of the elements you want to remove, you can use the function [in1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) provided by numpy.

The function returns `True` if the element of a 1-D array is also present in a second array. To delete the elements, you just have to negate the values returned by this function.

Notice that this method **keeps the order** from the original array.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

        a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
        rm = np.array([3, 4, 7])
        # np.in1d return true if the element of `a` is in `rm`
        idx = np.in1d(a, rm)
        idx

Out[1]: array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False])

In [2]: # Since we want the opposite of what `in1d` gives us, 
        # you just have to negate the returned value
        a[~idx]

Out[2]: array([1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the index, you can't use `logical_and`

```
x = 10*np.random.randn(1,100)
low = 5
high = 27
x[0,np.logical_and(x[0,:]>low,x[0,:]<high)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove specific index(i removed 16 and 21 from matrix)

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.arange(12,26)
a = [4,9]
del_map = np.delete(mat, a)
del_map.reshape(3,4)
```

Output:

```
array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
      [17, 18, 19, 20],
      [22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

Answer (score 2):

list comprehension could be an interesting approach as well.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
index = np.array([2, 3, 6]) #index is changed to an array.  
out = [val for i, val in enumerate(a) if all(i != index)]
>>> [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not know the indices now you can do something like this:

```py
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
values = [3, 4, 7]
mask = np.isin(arr, values)
arr = np.delete(arr, mask)
```

This syntax with mask was [introduced in 1.19](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sets:

```
a = numpy.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
the_index_list = [2, 3, 6]

the_big_set = set(numpy.arange(len(a)))
the_small_set = set(the_index_list)
the_delta_row_list = list(the_big_set - the_small_set)

a = a[the_delta_row_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter the part that you do not need:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
a = a[(a!=3)&(a!=4)&(a!=7)]
```

If you have a list of indices to be removed:

```
to_be_removed_inds = [2,3,6]
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
a = a[[x for x in range(len(a)) if x not in to_be_removed]]
```