# Python: list vs. np.array: switching to use certain attributes

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, type-conversion

I know, there are plenty of threads about list vs. array but I've got a slightly different problem.

Using Python, I find myself converting between np.array and list quite often as I want to use attributes like

remove, append, extend, sort, index, … for lists

and on the other hand modify the content by things like

*, /, +, -, np.exp(), np.sqrt(), … which only works for arrays.

It must be pretty messy to switch between data types with list(array) and np.asarray(list), I assume. But I just can't think of a proper solution. I don't really want to write a loop every time I want to find and remove something from my array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why exactly do you think you need to switch back to a list?

Comment: It happens that I need the remove some elements from the list after I've calculated something with all elements.

Comment: `numpy.delete` will remove items from an array, if that's the only reason you are switching back to a list. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996140/how-to-remove-specific-elements-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Also you can use numpy indexing to remove elements of an array. `x = np.arange(5); mask = x>2; print( x[mask] )` will print only `array([3, 4])` without needing to convert to a list.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A numpy array:

```
>>> A=np.array([1,4,9,2,7])
```

delete:

```
>>> A=np.delete(A, [2,3])
>>> A
array([1, 4, 7])
```

append (beware: it's **O(n)**, unlike list.append which is **O(1)**):

```
>>> A=np.append(A, [5,0])
>>> A
array([1, 4, 7, 5, 0])
```

sort:

```
>>> np.sort(A)
array([0, 1, 4, 5, 7])
```

index:

```
>>> A
array([1, 4, 7, 5, 0])
>>> np.where(A==7)
(array([2]),)
```

Comment: Why did I think these attributes didn't exist for numpy arrays? No idea. Thank you.

Comment: @quarky Note however that there is a fundamental difference in performance between `list.append` and `np.append`. While the former one [has a complexity O(1)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) (i.e. executes in a fixed time), the later one is O(n) and the run time increases with the array size `n`, because very time the whole array will be reallocated. For instance, creating a list in a for loop with `append` is fine, while doing so with Numpy should be avoided at all costs. So those methods do exist in numpy, but you should understand the performance consequences before using them.

Comment: @quarky My point is that, `remove`, `append`, `extend` are rarely used in numpy, because often there is a more efficient way of achieving the same  goal.

Comment: okay, thanks. I wasn't aware of this. I will think about how to improve my code considering this.