# Removing a single element (not an entire row/column) from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to remove just a single element in a 2d numpy array?

For example, let's say I have:
    `x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`

and I want the new version of x to just store `np.array([[1], [3, 4]])`.

Is this doable?

Comment: AFAIK you need to make a new array.

Comment: Actually, have you tried entering `np.array([[1], [3, 4]])` to see what you get? I'm pretty sure it's not possible. Flatten it and then delete the unwanted element using the method described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: That's the wrong duplicate.  This isn't a 1d array. `np.delete` does not work.  Actually nothing works like this.

Comment: Show us how you would do this task on `x1=x.tolist()`.

Comment: wrong 1d array delete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996140/how-to-remove-specific-elements-in-a-numpy-array; it may help asnwer the question, but it isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

As a list operation this is straight forward:

```
In [328]: x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

Just use the `list` `del` to remove the desired element:

```
In [337]: xl=x.tolist()
In [338]: idx=(0,1)
In [339]: del xl[idx[0]][idx[1]]
In [340]: xl
Out[340]: [[1], [3, 4]]
```

It can be turned back into an array - but it will be jagged, and hence an array of lists:

```
In [341]: np.array(xl)
Out[341]: array([[1], [3, 4]], dtype=object)
```

You could also use `np.delete` to remove this element from a flattened version of the array:

```
In [343]: np.ravel_multi_index(idx,x.shape)
Out[343]: 1
In [344]: np.delete(x,np.ravel_multi_index(idx,x.shape))
Out[344]: array([1, 3, 4])
```

You can't go back to the 2d array.  It could be split into row arrays:

```
In [345]: np.split(_,[1])
Out[345]: [array([1]), array([3, 4])]
```

Calculating that split index will be a bit more tedious in the general case.