# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: python

```
_, contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours( img1, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_, contours1, hierarchy = cv.findContours( thresh1, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i in contours0[0]:
     if i in contours1[0]:
        contours0[0].delete(i)
print(contours0)
```

This yields AttributeError: `numpy.ndarray` object has no attribute `delete`
What could be the error? I want to remove matching elements from contour.

Comment: numpy arrays do not have a `delete()` method. Instead, you have to use `numpy.delete(contours0[0], index)` where `index` is the position of `i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove specific elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996140/how-to-remove-specific-elements-in-a-numpy-array)