# Numpy array : NOT select specific rows or columns

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a simple numpy array. I want to select all rows but 1st and 6th
I tried:

```
temp = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
t = temp[~[0,5]]
```

I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove specific elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996140/how-to-remove-specific-elements-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.delete` to delete elements at a specific index position:

```
t = np.delete(temp, [0, 5])
```

Or you can create an boolean array, than it is possible to *negate* the indices:

```
bool_idx = np.zeros(len(temp), dtype=bool)
bool_idx[[0, 5]] = True
t = temp[~bool_idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant create the indices that way. Instead you could create a range of numbers from 0 to `temp.size` and delete the unwanted indices:

```
In [19]: ind = np.delete(np.arange(temp.size), [0, 5])

In [21]: temp[ind]
Out[21]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9])
```

Or just create it like following:

```
In [16]: ind = np.concatenate((np.arange(1, 5), np.arange(6, temp.size)))

In [17]: temp[ind]
Out[17]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) numpy object which concatenates the array into by breaking them using the indices giving the resultant output.

```
np.r_[temp[1:5], temp[6:]]
```

The code above concatenates the two arrays which are sliced from the original array  and hence the resultant array without the indices specified.