# Numpy equivalent of trim_zeros for other values

Tags: numpy

I want to trim a 1D numpy array by removing all elements from left and right that are a certain value (e.g. 255). It seems a bit silly to do all the extra work of

np.trim_zeros(arr - 255) + 255

Is there an equivalent `trim` function which allows you to specify the values that trigger removal? Or can I perhaps roll my own by looking at the internals of `trim_zeros`?

Comment: `np.trim_zeros` is Python code, and fairly obvious.  Read it and write your own.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55864896/1161132. Not sure internally how where is implemented so it may want to look into performance.

Comment: `trim_zeros` does 2 things.  1) find the slice we want to keep (the bounds of the nonzero block), 2) return that slice.

Comment: @hpaulj - thanks. Silly me - I didn't see it was a python function, just assumed it was in C.

Answer (score 0):

@hpaulj pointed out that the code for `trim_zeros` is written in python and very simple to modify. So the following code will work fine, and should be as fast as the built in `trim_zeros`.

```
def trim(filt, trim_value=0., trim='fb'):
    """
    Copied from np.trim_zeros, but allows the trim value to be specified
    """
    first = 0
    trim = trim.upper()
    if 'F' in trim:
        for i in filt:
            if i != trim_value:
                break
            else:
                first = first + 1
    last = len(filt)
    if 'B' in trim:
        for i in filt[::-1]:
            if i != trim_value:
                break
            else:
                last = last - 1
    return filt[first:last]
```

It might be nice to add this to the numpy codebase, I guess.