# Torch complement of index operation

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor, torch

I have a tensor say `t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and a list of indices I want to remove like `d = [0, 2, 5]`.

Doing `t[d]` gives me the subtensor with the elements I want to remove.

How can I used `d` to get the subtensor with all the elements **except** the ones indexed in `d`. There must be something like `t[~d]`, right?

Something like numpy's [numpy.delete](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).

Comment: `np.delete` is not a simple function.  It does different things depending dimensions and index.  You might want to read its code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove specific elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996140/how-to-remove-specific-elements-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Yup, that last way to create a mask seems to work and it's pretty fast. Feel free to post it as an answer or I guess I can. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

`delete` uses logic like

```
mask= np.ones(t.shape, dtype=bool)
mask[d] = False
res = t[mask]
```

`mask` is a bool that is true for all indices we want to keep.  This is the simple 1d version.

```
In [3]: t=np.arange(1,10); d= np.array([0,2,5])

In [4]: mask = np.ones(t.shape, bool)
In [5]: mask[d] = False
In [6]: mask
Out[6]: array([False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True])

In [7]: t[mask]
Out[7]: array([2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9])
```