# How do I substract elements from an array from the last index to the previous one?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of numbers such as (only as an example) [40, 23, 15, 8]. I want to substract the last elemet to the previous one, and then. It'd look like [40-23, 23-15, 15-8, 8]. I want to apply this for an arbitrary array that goes from biggest to smallest.

I know I should iterate over my array but I'm currently blank on how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove specific elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996140/how-to-remove-specific-elements-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `numpy` for this, it's easily accomplished in raw Python by iterating over the indices:

```
>>> a = [40, 23, 15, 8]
>>> [a[i] - sum(a[i + 1:]) for i in range(len(a))]
[-6, 0, 7, 8]
# The above answers the original question,
# in which the OP said: It'd look like [40-23-15-8, 23-15-8, 15-8, 8].
# - where all subsequent elements are subtracted from the first.
# As the question has now been edited, the following
# code answers the current version:
>>> [a[i] - (a[i + 1] if i < len(a) - 1 else 0) for i in range(len(a))]
[17, 8, 7, 8]
```

Comment: @BigBen Ah, well the OP has edited the question now.   My code answers the original question!

Comment: Also it's tagged [tag:numpy] ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) would be to add a zero to the end, compute a [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and invert the output:

```
l = [40, 23, 15, 8]
out = -np.diff(np.r_[l, 0])
```

Alternatively:

```
l = [40, 23, 15, 8]

out = np.array(l)
out[:-1] -= out[1:]
```

Output: `array([17,  8,  7,  8])`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import numpy library
import numpy as np

# Given an array of numbers
array = [40, 23, 15, 8]

# Use np.diff to calculate the difference between adjacent elements
diff_array = np.diff(array)

# Print the result
print(diff_array)
```

**Output**

```
[17, 8, 7]
```

Comment: That's not the correct output, right? OP is looking for `[17, 8, 7, 8]`.